# Developing Cartography for Simulated Land Navigation or Orienteering

Tags: game-design, maps, godot, arma3

Request to know what the best approach for developing a simulated Large 1:75,000 or 1:50,000 scaled map using [GODOT](https://godotengine.org/) or another game engine. My goal would be to create a 3D world that allows the player to view a 2D map which is similar to real world [USGS/NGA](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/advanced-viewer/) style maps using UTM/MGRS for land based navigation. Later I would add tools such as the [Cammenga](https://cammenga.com/product/compasses/tritium-compass-3h/) 6605-01-196-6971 Compass and a [Maptools](https://maptools.com/) style protractor. I have spend hours searching for examples of GODOT developed games using maps similar to approaches used in [Arma 3](https://arma3.com/) and [Firewatch](http://www.firewatchgame.com/). I would greatly appreciate any advice on techniques used with GODOT or other game engines to create a mapping system for players. Thank You!

Comment: There is never a *best* approach to any given problem. Only the best approach for your particular requirements..

Comment: It is unclear to me what you've tried so far or how the results you've achieved differ from what you want. What specific step do you need help with?

Comment: I've put the question on hold as unclear for the moment. Can you please edit your question to describe what one feature or step in the process you need help with, or what specific problem you need help solving? Vague requests for "any advice" are too broad for this site — maybe try working through some tutorials to get your bearings, then you can ask about specific content/behaviours not covered in those tutorials?